# Syntax error unexpected tSTRING_BEG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to call a parameter inside a call to Rails.application.secrets but I have a syntax error.. Sorry if the answer seems evident, I am new to ruby.

Here is the code

```
  def sign_up_url_secret(secret_network)
    secret_key = Rails.application.secrets.'#{secret_network}'
    "#{Rails.application.secrets.platform_signup_url}?team_secret=#{secret_key}"
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from this:

```
secret_key = Rails.application.secrets.'#{secret_network}'
```

You can't call a method like that in Ruby.

You can use [public_send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) or [send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to do that:

```
def sign_up_url_secret(secret_network)
  secret_key = Rails.application.secrets.public_send(secret_network)
  "#{Rails.application.secrets.platform_signup_url}?team_secret=#{secret_key}"
end
```

Comment: Never do `"#{secret_network}"`. If you know the value is a string (or don't care about its type), use it directly: `secret_network`. If you're not sure if it's a string and you need it to be a string, use `secret_network.to_s`. Only use string interpolation (`#{...}`) when you want to interpolate the value into a string with other content, as you do on the third line.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my answer to reflect that.